# Scrubbing HTML video is jerky in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, video

HTML video is much choppier when scrubbing with range input on Chrome or Firefox than it is if viewed on Safari, Internet Explorer 11 or Edge.

Is there any way to help Chrome & Firefox be as buttery smooth as the other browsers?

--- UPDATE ---

Strangely, it appears smoother when running the snippet when posted, than in the snippet editor itself (and unfortunately, on the page I'm trying to use it on).

That being said, here are a couple of examples where the different browser behaviors is more apparent:

1) On the CodePen where that I drew inspiration from:

https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc

2) On JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L9fdyg3j/42/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vid = document.getElementById('vid'); 
  var playbackConst = 500; 
  var initialized = false;

  vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    if (!initialized){
      var slider = $('#slide');
      // set slider max according to video length
      var lastFrame = Math.floor(vid.duration) * playbackConst;
      slider.attr('max', lastFrame);
      // set slider to middle position
      slider.attr('value', lastFrame/2);
      // also start video in the middle
      vid.currentTime  = lastFrame/(2 * playbackConst);
      // Pause the video immediately ...
      vid.pause();
      initialized = true;
    }
  });

  // set video to current position of the slider when slider input is modified
  $(document).on('input change', 'input', function() {
    vid.currentTime  = $(this).val()/playbackConst;
  });

});
```

```css
#slide{
  width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="vid" muted playsinline autoplay="true" preload="auto" >
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4">
  <p>Your browser does not support video playback</p>
</video>

<br>
<input id="slide" type="range" >
<br>
```

Comment: Did you notice this before adding the style to the slider or after? Maybe try a % rather than a set pixel width. Just a thought...

Comment: I don't notice a problem in Firefox or Chrome. Seems smooth to me.

Comment: The slider styling doesn't seem to make a difference. I removed the width restriction on the video. Also, I posted some links to JSFiddle and CodePen where the behavior seems more pronounced than StackOverflow's (apparently superior) code snippets.